# Two-stage validation in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm working in a content development scenario where entities are likely to be created in an incomplete state and remain incomplete for some time. The workflow involved is extremely ad-hoc, preventing me from using a more structured DDD approach.

I have a set of validation rules which must be satisfied at all times, and a further set of validation rules which must be satisfied before an entity is "complete".

I'm already using the built-in ASP.NET MVC validation to validate the former. What approaches could I use to capture the latter?

For example:-

```
public class Foo
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [Required] // A Bar must be owned by a Foo at all times
  public int FooId { get; set; }
  public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }

  [Required] // A Bar must have a working title at all times
  public string WorkingTitle { get; set; }

  public bool IsComplete { get; set; }

  // Cannot use RequiredAttribute on Description as the
  // entity is very likely to be created without one,
  // however a Description is required before the entity
  // can be marked as "IsComplete"
  public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different approaches you could use:

- Have your model implement the [`IValidatableObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.aspx) interface and perform conditional validation without using data annotations.
- Write a custom validation attribute that will perform the conditional validation logic of the `Description` property based on the value of the `IsComplete` property.
- Use [Mvc Foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) which already has the `RequiredIf` validation attribute defined for you so that you don't need to write it yourself.
- Use [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) which allows you to express your validation rules in a fluent manner. Writing conditional validation rules using this library is not only elegant but very easy. It [integrates nicely with ASP.NET MVC](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation) and also allows you to easily [unit test your validation logic](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Testing&referringTitle=Documentation) in isolation.

Personally I would go with the FV.NET but you could use any of the other approaches if it better suits your needs.

Comment: Gah! Conditional validation based on the value of the "IsComplete" field. Why didn't I think of that! /facepalm.